(God Rays) Object ray visibility for camera is turned off and looks fine in viewport Rendered view but not when Rendering image
as stated above I have a scene where the sun shines light towards the camera and there are god rays visible. This is what it looks like in rendered view.
Rendered View

As you can see, the rays are visible.
However, when rendering the image, the rays disappear.
Render:

In the corner, there is a plane with holes to create this effect and a cube with volume scatter shader added.
Plane:


Box surround the scene:


Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

@Crow I converted your post to a comment; there was a comment from Scoobyjeww: "turning off denoising did not fix the render. It still looks the same"
